# How can I reassign opportunities in Salesforce based on number of opportunities per account?

Tags: salesforce

I have created a simple class and visual force page that displays a "group by". The output is perfect, it will display the number of opportunities a given account has:

```
  lstAR = [ select Account.Name AccountName, AccountId, Count(CampaignID) CountResult from Opportunity where CampaignID != null group by Account.Name,AccountId having COUNT(CampaignID) > 0 LIMIT 500 ];
```

I would like to be able to say, if an account has more then 10 opportunities, then assign the opportunity to another account that has less then 10.

I used the following code to get the results in my visual force page:

```
public list<OppClass> getResults() {  
  list<OppClass> lstResult = new list<OppClass>();  
  for (AggregateResult ar: lstAR) {  
    oppClass objOppClass = new oppClass(ar);  

      lstResult.add(objOppClass);  
  }

  return lstResult;  
}  

class oppClass {  
  public Integer CountResult { get;set; }  

  public String AccountName { get;set; }  

  public String AccountID { get;set; }

  public oppClass(AggregateResult ar) {  
    //Note that ar returns objects as results, so you need type conversion here  
    CountResult = (Integer)ar.get('CountResult');  

    AccountName = (String)ar.get('AccountName');  
    AccountID = (String)ar.get('AccountID');
  }
```

What would be the best approach to check the count greater then a given number and then assign an account with less then that given number the opportunities?

As I said, code wise I have a nice little controller and vf page that will display the account and count in a grid. Just not sure of a good approach to do the reassigning opportunity.

Thanks
Frank

Comment: Not an answer, but I'm just curious - what do Opportunity objects represent in your business model? "Assign an opportunity to an account with less than 10 opportunities" is a very unusual requirement in the SFDC world.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd be moving your opportunity to another account b/c typically the account is the organization/person buying the stuff?
But that said, ignoring the why and focusing on the how...

Trigger on the Opportunity, before insert

loop over trigger.new and count how many oppties you have per account (or owner) in that batch, put that into a map accountId to count [because you could be inserting 10 oppties for the same account!]. If ever your count is > 10 change the assignment using whatever assignment helper class you have.
Also populate set of accountIds.

Then run your aggregate for each account where Id in set of accountIds, you'll have to group by AccountId.

Loop over results, and update the map of accountId to count.

Then loop over trigger.new and for each oppty, look up in the map by accountId the count. If the count > 10 then do your assignment using your helper class.

And done.

Of course your assignment helper class is another issue to tackle - how do you know which account/user to assign the opportunity to, are you going to use queues, custom objects, custom settings to govern the rules, etc...

But the concept above should work...